# Mapbox GL JS - toggling 2 layers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I'm using Mapbox's [Show and Hide Layer example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) where the user can toggle on/off layers, but seem to be running into an issue I can't pinpoint.

**What I did**

In Mapbox's example, I replace the first layer (Museum's) with my data and left their "contour" data alone.  My data is an obvious big black blog for simplicity.

**The result**

The toggle switch appears to work by changing color when turning on/off,  however my big black blog on my map isn't disappearing.

**Actions taken**

I tried countless times to slowly piece together portions of the code to see where it fails, but just not understanding where I'm going wrong. My guess it's the map.addSource versus map.addLayer which I may not be understanding the difference.  My data was uploaded to a Tileset via a zipped shapefile. 
 Perhaps the example being used is from a GeoJson?

[Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/pacoventry/67mLoau1/8/), *except the access token is missing for security purposes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implemented the toggle on/off functionality right.

Your layer is not visible, because the alpha channel (which specifies the opacity for a color) of `fill-color` and `fill-outline-color` is 0.
Setting them both e.g. to 1 your layer becomes visible.

```
'fill-color': 'rgba(72, 67, 45, 1)',
'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
```

Your style `mapbox://styles/pacoventry/cjfh33iu93ld62rjvlqfo8re7` wasn't available for me, so I replaced it with `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9` in the following jsbin (just enter your Mapbox token):

http://jsbin.com/wijapekomi/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm almost there, just one more question.  That 'black blob' layer really isn't my working layer, but rather a layer with 8 specific colors.  Do I have to add each of those rgba colors in the area you indicated above? or is there a way to reference the colors in my Tileset? I have an example of a map that has the toggling function where there are multiple colors in the layer.  I'm just not seeing how it's being referenced in the code?  https://jsfiddle.net/pacoventry/zjdeq5vn/    (it's the bottom 2 buttons)

Comment: If your question 'Mapbox GL JS - toggling 2 layers' is solved, please accept my answer and open a new question regarding the layer colors.

Comment: You may reference the colors in your tileset with expressions, example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/.

Comment: Thank you pathmappers and I'm sorry to have added that additional question to my original.  You answered both questions and I greatly appreciate your help!!